# NestJS mongoose aggregate $lookup .exec() check if there are no data

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs, aggregate

so my goal is when i make a requests to the database, check if theres no data returned from the database.

Can you help me? Thanks!

Heres my code:

```
    let rqs: any = this.friendrequestModel
      .aggregate([
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "users",
            localField: "author",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "userdata",
            // pipeline: [
            //   {
            //     $match: {
            //       friend_id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userid)
            //     }
            //   }
            // ],
          },
        },
      ])
      .exec((err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }

        if(!data){
          console.log("No data returned")
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you're performing an aggregation query using Mongoose, and you want to check if there is no data returned from the database. However, the current approach with **`if (!data)`** won't work as expected because even if the **`data`** variable is empty or contains no elements, it won't be falsy, and the condition will not be met.

To check if there is no data returned from the database, you can modify your code as follows:

```js
let rqs: any = this.friendrequestModel
  .aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "users",
        localField: "author",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "userdata",
      },
    },
  ])
  .exec((err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return; // Exit early if there's an error
    }

    if (data.length === 0) {
      console.log("No data returned");
    }
  });
```